# Stability of parameters in sde

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

From lecture notes on SDE's.

Consider the Stratonovich equation $dX_t=rX_tdt+\sigma X_t\circ dB_t$. It has initial condition $X_0=x$. What are the conditions for the parameters $(\sigma,r)$, for $\mathbb{E}(X_t)$ and $\mathbb{E}(X_t^2)$ to stay bounded as $t\rightarrow \infty$?

I thought about using the Dynkin formula, but I think this has more to do with stochastic stability? I am not sure which theorem to use, at there does not seem to be some general approach?

Comment: It means that we use Stratonovich noise. Does that change the argument?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that, sorry.

Comment: @thaumoctopus Could you please give some context behind this question? Second, if this were a standard Ito SDE, is there a way to characterize the parameters $\sigma$ and $r$ so that the first and second moments remain bounded?